# Add CSS class to PHP Statement

Tags: php, theme-development, css

A newbie question, I have been trying to style certain PHP code and I keep hitting the wall. I need to add CSS class to the **No results found** text bellow:

```
        <?php } 
        else{
            esc_html_e('No results found','ThemeName');             
        }

        ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in an HTML element that has a class. Doing it with your code will require changes.

You can either do it outside the PHP, which will require changing where you open and close the PHP tags:

```
<?php } else { ?>
    <span class="classname">
        <?php esc_html_e('No results found','ThemeName'); ?>
    </span>
<?php } ?>
```

You can do it inside the PHP by concatenating a string, which means you'll need to use `esc_html__()` instead of `esc_html_e()` (which echoes the result, which you shouldn't do in the middle of a concatenation):

```
<?php 
} else {
    echo '<span class="classname">' . esc_html__('No results found','ThemeName') . '</span>';
}
?>
```

Or use `printf()` to put the string together, also using `esc_html__()`:

```
<?php 
} else {
    printf( '<span class="classname">%s</span>', esc_html__( 'No results found', 'ThemeName' ) );
}
?>
```